# Programmatically identify current eclipse instance

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin, where I communicate between client and plugin side over a port on localhost. The problem is, that it fails if multiple instances of eclipse are running at the same time, so I need to somehow identify matching instances. For the used framework (SIMON), it's no problem, there is a registry where I can easily use different identifiers, but how to find out which client instance is running on the same eclipse as which plugin instance?

My Idea is to somehow access the current workspace's directory from both sides and communicate  using a file. From a plugin, it's easy to do so, but is it also (cleanly) possible from any java project?

Comment: TCP ports within the same pair of endpoints are guaranteed to be unique as long as the respective connections are open. Can you use these?

Comment: What's a client? Would you describe an architecture?

Comment: It's a bit complicated: I have a plugin. And, in order to use my tool, a programmer must use methods of some library inside his project. This library (written by me and previously called "client") communicates to my plugin using SIMON (http://dev.root1.de/projects/simon), which works similar to RMI. But this mechanism gets confused if several eclipse instances are running.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the feature of Eclipse EMF that generates a universal unique ID:

```
EcoreUtil.generateUUID()
```

You could have each client and server generate a UUID and use that to distinguish between different instances.

Comment: The problem is: My client is not an eclipse plugin... But I could probably write it into a file in the workspace's root directory and search for this one...

Comment: The client can always ask any server to give it a UUID.  It would save that UUID and never ask again.